# How to fix this error Idk?

Tags: oracle, rman

[image]

how to fix it I am new in Oracle?

I tried to connect RMAN and it showed me this error...

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an instance on your own machine?  The "/" syntax implies you are trying to connect locally, but the "client_1" in the path implies you are not running a server locally.

Answer (score -1):

please check your `alert.log` for your database instance 
`(your database instance must running)`.

if you use catalog database, it must be open `(the target database does not need to be open)`.